# How to disable some of the checkboxes based on checked radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

As the title says, I want to disable some of the checkboxes based on the checked radio button.

For example, I click the first radio button `id="pz1"` and then it disables the checkboxes which `id` is the same as listed in `thisToppings` array. Every radio button has its respective checkboxes to be disabled.

So far, I can only disable the first four checkboxes out of six in the first radio button. While the other radio button, the checkboxes disabling function doesn't work at all. And every time I clicked any of the radio buttons it will give an error that `id` in `xxToppings[i].id` is undefined.

I want to complete this in vanilla Javascript, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**script.js**

```
const pzPrice = form.elements.pz;
const toppingsPrice = form.elements.topping;

    pzPrice[0].onclick = () => {
    const thisToppings = [
        { id: "tp0" },
        { id: "tp1" },
        { id: "tp2" },
        { id: "tp3" },
        { id: "tp7" },
        { id: "tp10" }
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < toppingsPrice.length; i++) {
        if (toppingsPrice[i].id === thisToppings[i].id) {
            toppingsPrice[i].disabled = true;
        } else toppingsPrice[i].disabled = false;
    }
};

pzPrice[1].onclick = () => {
    const thisOtherToppings = [
        { id: "tp1" },
        { id: "tp2" },
        { id: "tp3" },
        { id: "tp4" },
        { id: "tp5" },
        { id: "tp6" },
        { id: "tp8" },
        { id: "tp10" }
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < toppingsPrice.length; i++) {
        if (toppingsPrice[i].id === thisOtherToppings[i].id) {
            toppingsPrice[i].disabled = true;
        } else toppingsPrice[i].disabled = false;
    }
};

pzPrice[2].onclick = () => {
    const theOtherToppings = [
        { id: "tp1" },
        { id: "tp2" },
        { id: "tp3" },
        { id: "tp7" },
        { id: "tp8" },
        { id: "tp9" },
        { id: "tp10" },
        { id: "tp11" }
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < toppingsPrice.length; i++) {
        if (toppingsPrice[i].id == theOtherToppings[i].id) {
            toppingsPrice[i].disabled = true;
        } else toppingsPrice[i].disabled = false;
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<form name="demo">
<section class="radio">
            <div class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="pz1" name="pz" value=8>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="pz2" name="pz" value=10>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="pz3" name="pz" value=12>
            </div>
</section>
<section class="choices">
            <div class="veggies">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp0" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp1" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp2" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp3" name="topping" value=1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="seafood">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp4" name="topping" value=2>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp5" name="topping" value=2>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp6" name="topping" value=2>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp7" name="topping" value=2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="meat">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp8" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp9" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp10" name="topping" value=1>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tp11" name="topping" value=1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry to say but your fundamental HTML structure and JS approach are going to make this solution very difficult to maintain. IDs are not needed at all and should be avoided most of the time because they cause the solution to be very brittle and not scale friendly. You should really just put classes on the radio buttons and then matching classes on the related checkboxes to easily create groupings between them. I also don't see the point of the 3 arrays you've made (again, managing ID's is not a good way to go).

Comment: Also, you really need to put some labels next to your radio buttons and checkboxes and come up with better variable names so that it's much easier to follow your code. Lastly, you should put all your `value`s in quotes to be consistent with all your other attributes.

Comment: I do have some labels in the real code, I just remove it here because it is not really related to my question. Thanks for the other feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you're suggesting that employs [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and better adheres to the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.

(See the in-code comments for further explanation.)

```js
// Identifies DOM elements
const
  form = document.querySelector("form"),
  toppingPrices = form.elements.topping;

// Calls `switchToppings` when something on the form is clicked
form.addEventListener("click", switchToppings);

// Listeners can automatically access their triggering events
function switchToppings(event){
  let list;
  const clickedThing = event.target; // `.target` property is useful
  if(clickedThing.name != "pz"){ return; } // Ignores uninteresting clicks

  // Selects list based on which radio was clicked
  if(clickedThing.id == "pz1"){ list = "tp0,tp1,tp2,tp3,tp7,tp10".split(","); }
  else if(clickedThing.id == "pz2"){ list = "tp1,tp2,tp3,tp4,tp5,tp6,tp8,tp10".split(","); }
  else if(clickedThing.id == "pz3"){ list = "tp1,tp2,tp3,tp7,tp8,tp9,tp10,tp11".split(","); }
  else{ console.log("no list found for this radio button"); return; }

  // Enables all checkboxes
  Array.from(toppingPrices).forEach(el => el.removeAttribute("disabled"));

  const
    // Collects checkboxes whose `id`s are found in the list
    disableMe = Array.from(toppingPrices).filter(el => list.includes(el.id));
  // Disables the collected checkboxes
  disableMe.forEach(el => el.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
};
```

```html
<form name="demo">
  <section class="radio">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" id="pz1" name="pz" value=8>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" id="pz2" name="pz" value=10>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" id="pz3" name="pz" value=12>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="choices">
    <div class="veggies">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp0" name="topping" value=1>0
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp1" name="topping" value=1>1
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp2" name="topping" value=1>2
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp3" name="topping" value=1>3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seafood">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp4" name="topping" value=2>4
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp5" name="topping" value=2>5
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp6" name="topping" value=2>6
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp7" name="topping" value=2>7
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meat">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp8"  name="topping" value=1>8
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp9"  name="topping" value=1>9
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp10" name="topping" value=1>10
        <input type="checkbox" id="tp11" name="topping" value=1>11
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is working as I hope to. I just tweaked some of it to fit my liking, like using switch-case instead of if-else.